# How to Migrate from accountKit to Firebase Phone sign up?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, account-kit

I'm using AccountKit for phone sign up right now in our mobile app. As AccountKit will be deprecated soon so we are migrating with firebase phone sign up. 
I have set up a new user/Sign-up flow but still confused about old users when they log-in again using a new sign-in method(Firebase).

**Current Login Process:**

1. Client request with the access token.
2. Server request to account kit with an access token and get user data with UID
3. By this UID I check in current database user present or not.

**Problem:**

When old user tries to sign in through firebase then I'll get different UID(UID of firebase) which is not present in my database so it will consider it as a new user.

Backend: Node js

Can someone help me what would be the best approach to migrate?

Comment: Hey Nishant, can you download all your accounts from Account Kit? If so, you can [re-upload](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/import-users#import_users_without_passwords) them to Firebase with their phone numbers. Also you can re-upload the accounts to Firebase with the same UIDs.

Comment: @bojeil Yes I checked AccountKit documentation and can download data https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/graphapi/#retrievedata. I'll try this approach